# Декомпиляция и компиляция проекта Android через APKTool

Tags: android-sdk, android, декомпиляция, компиляция

Добрый день!

Интересует такой вопрос, есть скомпилированный проект Android (.apk), задача - так как выпуск apk делается под разные сервера, нужно менять некие настройки в XML файле Settings.xml но без физической перекомпиляции проекта через Eclipse.

Частичное решение такое - написан скрипт который декомпилит .apk используя apktool меняет значения в Settings.XML и после этого опять же компилит все через apktool.

Однако, как показала практика, данная apk собранная таким образом не ставиться на реальном устройстве android. выдается простое сообщение - "Application not installed"

Погуглив по интернету найдено следующее - 
http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#cert

собранный через apktool файл .apk необходимо подписать,  однако,при попытке сгенерировать эту самую подпись через команду

ant release

получаю ошибку - build.xml not found

**Краткое уточнение**
Переконфигурацию и пересборку будут производить на другом компьютере где нет установленного eclipse. Нужно сделать что то типа пересборщика. Естественно - что некоторые вещи, такие как android-sdk поставить на тот компьютер все равно придется :)

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: думаю, проще настроить ant/gradle для создания нужного кол-ва бинарников. Проще и надежнее.

Comment: Не могли бы вы рассказать поподробнее, что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: для gradle (это в android studio система сборки) есть [flavours](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-flavors). Это именно то, что нужно. Просто описываете различия и gradle все соберет сам.

Если же используете eclipse без gradle, тогда [antenna](http://antenna.sourceforge.net/) - препроцессор для java. Но работа с ним - это особый шарм:)

Comment: На сколько мне известно Android Studio - это google студия для разработки под Android. Так сказать аналогия Eclipse. Однако еще раз уточню - на компьютере где будет конфигурироваться софт - нет Android разработчиков вовсе, т.е. задача моя написать конфигуратор,  который за собой будет тащить sdk и еще что то - для пересборки проекта одной кнопкой

Comment: Вам нужно будет один раз настроить gradle для своего проекта (для этого студия как раз и нужна, можно ручками, но это на первых порах будет немного сложнее.

На другие компы нужно будет устанавливать jdk и android sdk (лучше сделать архив самостоятельно с нужными пакетами). И все.

А те, кому нужно будет собрать проект, просто запустят gradle  с командной строки передав параметры, которые укажут, что именно нужно собрать и в каком кол-ве. Так как gradle основан на groovy, то возможности для сборки очень широкие - по факту ограничиваются только фантазией.

Comment: Вадим, спасибо за помощь! Android программированием занимаюсь 5 лет, но тем не менее задам первый вопрос любого начинающего - на примере не обьясните? (как один раз настроить gradle) :) Или направьте пожалуйста на толковый мануал

Comment: я выше дал самую прямую ссылку.

Answer (score 3):

Вообщем решение найдено. Все достаточно просто оказалось

Пойду с начала и попытаюсь сэкономить время другим разработчикам. Логика такова:

1. есть файл apk
2. есть веб часть
3. Элемент списка
4. выставили настройки
5. нажали сконфигурировать
6. скрипт скрыто запустил батник apktool
7. декомпилировался проект
8. изменили значения нужные и в нужных местах
9. запустился батник apk tool - опять же скрыто
10. сжали и получили готовый проект
11. Подписали apk готовым ключем.

Все, на этом ваша apk готова к работе.

Для декомпиляции проекта нужно использовать

```
/Users/test/apktool/apktool d /Users/test/apktool/testproject.apk
```

Для компиляции

```
/Users/test/apktool/apktool b /Users/test/apktool/testproject
```

Чтобы подписать файл apk (после сборки apktool), нужно использовать стандартную утилиту для генерации ключа

*командная строка*

```
keytool -genkey -keystore mykeys.keystore -storepass spassword -alias mykey1 -keypass     kpassword1 -dname “CN=Test Test O=StartAndroid C=RU” -validity 10000
```

*ну лично мне приятнее использовать визуальный интерфейс, ведь нужно создать только один ключ, а потом использовать его сколь угодно раз. Кстати, ключ далеко не обязательно должен иметь расширение .keystore он может иметь расширение .jks*

Подпись апк происходит тоже весьма просто

*командная строка*

```
jarsigner -keystore /Volumes/workDisk/WorkProject/KeysForDroid/TestProject/testproject.jks  -storepass qwe123 -keypass qwe123 /Volumes/workDisk/WorkProject/KeysForDroid/TestProject/testproject.apk testproject
```

Естественно, что Eclipse, что Android Studio имеют визуальные средства для подписи apk ключем, но конкретно в моем случае цель была сделать это из консоли.

**Конкретно, весь механизм рассмотрен здесь**

http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/221-urok-123-kak-podpisat-prilozhenie-utility-keytool-i-jarsigner.html